# windbg, windows print driver

Tags: windows, printing, windbg

I am seeing this line in Windbg while debugging a windwos print driver

COemUni2::QueryInterface NULL. Returning E_NOINTERFACE.
BITMAP:  COemUni2::GetInfo() exit pcbNeeded is NULL! ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

What does this mean and what is pcbNeeded?. It looks like no processing happens after this line and windbg doesn't log anything.
Windbg is attached to notepad.exe and I am printing to the driver

Comment: Funny thing is that it's a line that you can find in the [driver samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/print/OEM%20Printer%20Customization%20Plug-in%20Samples/C%2B%2B/bitmap/intrface.cpp#L941).

Comment: As Nietsa commented it is a src linein the windows print driver sample andit appears you havenot installed or registered aninterface i think youneedthe BITMAP interface too and pcbNeededis a pointer which getsfilledup like   ULONG foo =0; function(..... ,&foo)

Comment: @Neitsa:  Interesting. Thank you. I didn't notice that its a line in the sample project itself :)

Comment: @blabb: Appreciate the explanation. That really helps. This whole world of driver development is hard. C++, windows driver kit and then debugging. Lots of variations.